# Duda sobre la correspondencia entre arreglos y punteros en C++

Tags: c++, punteros

He estado estudiando con un libro de C++ pero me ha surgido una duda con respecto a lo siguiente:

Sabemos que cuando asignamos el "asterisco" a una variable nos indica que se va a guardar el contenido de esta, pero cuando la variable carece del "asterisco" nos indica que va a guardar la posicion en memoria. Como en este ejemplo

```
int arrays[5]= {1,2,3,4,5};
int *puntero;
puntero = &var[0]
```

La pregunta surge del siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float V[6], *P[6];
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
        V[j] = (5-j) * 10 + 1;
        *(P+j) = &V[j]; // inicialización de array de punteros
        cout<<"Ver: "<<P+j<<endl;
    }
    cout << " Direccion Contenido" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j<6; j++){
        cout << " V+" << j << " = " << *(P+j) << " = *(P+" << j << ")";
        cout << " V[" << j <<"] = " << **(P+j) << "\n";
    } 
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

¿ Porqué cuando inicializamos el array de punteros obligatoriamente nos toca poner el **asterisco**, si lo que se va a guardar allí es la posición en memoria, no el valor asignado ?

```
*(P+j) = &V[j];
```

Y al final, ¿ Porqué nos toca poner doble asterisco para poder mostrar el contenido del arreglo ?

```
cout << " V[" << j <<"] = " << **(P+j) << "\n";
```

Comment: Porque sí que estás guardando el valor asignado (por eso hace falta el  `*`), pero en este caso el valor asignado es una dirección. El array de punteros se implementa mediante un puntero al array. Por tanto tienes un puntero a otros punteros. Un **importante detalle de sintaxis**:  `a[i]` equivale para el compilador a `*(a+i)` y viceversa. Por tanto en tu caso `*(P+j)` es lo mismo que `P[j]`. Quizás usando esta otra sintaxis lo entiendas mejor. La signación sería `P[j]= &var[0]` y el uso sería `<< *P[j]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te estás confundiendo con un serio lío de conceptos. Vamos a aclararlos.

---

> Duda sobre la correspondencia entre arreglos y punteros en C++

No hay correspondencia alguna entre arreglos y punteros en C++. Son cosas distintas, una cosa son los arreglos y otra cosa son los punteros.

- Un arreglo<sup>1</sup> es un tipo básico del lenguaje que organiza una colección de objetos de manera anexa en memoria.
- Un puntero es un tipo básico del lenguaje que almacena direcciones de memoria a datos y puede ser usado para acceder a ellos.

> Sabemos que cuando asignamos el "asterisco" a una variable nos indica que se va a guardar el contenido de esta

No sabemos eso, porque eso no es cierto. No se le asignan asteriscos a las variables, el asterisco al que te refieres forma parte de la definición de la variable no forma parte de la variable en si:

```
           inicialización
                  ^
  definición      |
      ^           |
      |           |
      |           |
/-----------\ /-------\
int *puntero1 = nullptr;
\---/\------/ \-------/
  |      |        |
  |      |        |
  |      |        |
  |      |        |
  v      |        |
tipo     |        |
         v        |
   identificador  |
                  v
            inicializador
```

Lo que nos dice la definición `int *puntero` es que `puntero` es una variable de tipo `int *` y el tipo `int *` es  *puntero a entero*.

Tampoco es cierto que un puntero guarde el contenido de una variable, un puntero guarda la posición de memoria de un dato, no el contenido del dato, básicamente lo has definido al revés:

> pero cuando la variable carece del "asterisco" nos indica que va a guardar la posicion en memoria

Cuando el tipo incluye un asterisco, es un puntero. Cuando carece de asteriscos es una instancia. Los asteriscos almacenan direcciones de memoria, las instancias almacenan datos.

---

Una vez aclarados los malentendidos, vamos a aclarar tu duda. En el lenguaje C++ el tipo de los arreglos se forma con su tipo de datos y su tamaño:

```
int arreglo[5]; // El tipo es 'int[5]'
```

El lenguaje C++ es de [tipado fuerte](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipado_fuerte), esto implica que un dato no puede cambiar su tipo, pero a a vez C++ permite conversiones de datos implícitas, las cuáles permitan que este código compile:

```
int caracter = 'a'; // El caraáter se convierte implícitamente a entero.
double doble = 100; // El entero se convierte implícitamente a doble.
```

Aparte de la [promoción aritmética](https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/10273/arithmetic-promotions-and-conversions) existen otros tipos de conversión implícita, como el decaimiento a puntero. Esta conversión hace que un tipo arreglo `tipo[tamaño]` se convierta implícitamente a puntero `tipo *` (perdiendo la información de tamaño) siendo equivalente a la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del arreglo:

```
int arreglo[5]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *puntero = arreglo; // Conversión implícita de 'int[5]' a 'int *'
std::cout << arreglo[0] << *puntero; // Muestra '11'
```

El nombre del arreglo se convierte implícitamente a un puntero al primer elemento del arreglo, por lo tanto, los tipos de las definiciones en tu código:

```
float V[6], *P[6];
//    ^^^^  ^^^^^
//      \      \__ float*[6]
//       \
//        \______ float[6]
```

Son `float[6]` para `V` y `float*[6]` para `P`, cuando `V` decae a puntero su tipo es `float*` (puntero a número de coma flotante) y cuando `P` decae su tipo es `float**` (puntero a puntero número de coma flotante).

Cuando el asterisco se usa como operador unario `*`<sup>2</sup> significa *dame una referencia a lo que apuntas*, por eso se conoce como el *operador de des-referencia*.

Sabiendo todo lo anterior, podemos entender esta expresión:

```
    *(P+j) = &V[j];
//  ^\---/
//  |   \
//  |    \____ P se convierte a 'float **' y lo avanzamos 'j' posiciones.
//  |
//   \____ Des-referencia el puntero 'float **', obteniendo 'float *'.
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocido como *formación* o en inglés *array*.

<sup>2</sup>Cuando el operador opera sobre un solo opeerado, es un operador unario.